# Is it possible to declare a function of the same name as the class outside the class body in React js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have been trying to resolve this problem ..HELP ME!

I am getting this error:

./src/components/App/App.js

Line 76:11:  Parsing error: Identifier 'App' has already been declared

App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import PlayList from "../PlayList/PlayList";
import SearchBar from "../SearchBar/SearchBar";
import SearchResults from "../SearchResults/SearchResults";
import spotify from "./util/spotify";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

   ....body of the class.....
}

 function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <a href="http://localhost:3000">Audiophile</a>
      </h1>
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBar onSearch={this.search} />
        <div className="App-PlayList">
          <SearchResults SearchResults={this.SearchResults} onAdd={this.doThese} />
          <PlayList playListTracks={this.state.playListTracks} onNameChange={this.updatePlaylistName} onRemove={this.removeTrack} onSave={this.savePlayList} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js :

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode> 
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: No. The error is telling you this. Just give it a different name.